# git fetch does not update .git/refs/remotes/origin/master

Tags: git

I have a local git repository cloned from a central server. The last commit of my local master branch is **commit 1**.

The central repository has a new **commit 2** in master branch.

I ran `git fetch origin master` to update my local refs, I found `refs/remotes/origin/master` does not update.

And then I checked `.git/FETCH_HEAD`. This is, however, already **commit 2**

My local config for the fetch:

```
[remote "origin"]
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        url = #########
```

Also I am able to login to central and check the bare repository there. `project.git/refs/heads/master` is **commit 2**

Then I tried to run `git pull origin master`. Surprisingly, **commit 2** is merged into my local repository.

And `git diff origin/master` even shows me the diffs between **commit 1** and **commit 2**. But origin and my local repository have the same contents at this point.

My questions are:

1. Why `git fetch` does not download the latest update from origin?
2. Why `git pull` still works in this case?
3. Is it a problem of my local config or the central config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run

```
git fetch origin
```

then `refs/remotes/origin/master` will be updated.

If you specify a single ref to git fetch origin, then it assumes you just want to pull that to FETCH_HEAD

you can run

```
git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

and that will also update

Comment: Thanks! Does git pull not update origin/master? Also sometimes I need git diff origin/master, so I need run git fetch origin before I check the diff, right?

Comment: `git pull` is just `git fetch` followed by either `git merge` or `git rebase` (with appropriate arguments)

Comment: Also, I'm used to running `git fetch --all` - both so I don't have to worry about what remote I'm currently tracking, and so that I get a very brief overview of what branches other people are currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `git fetch origin master`—or, if you use `git pull`, it can do this for you—that *should* update your `origin/master`.

This kind of updating, however, was first put into Git in version 1.8.4 (released August 2013).  Some extremely out of date distributions still use Git version 1.7.x.  If you have such an ancient Git, `git fetch origin master` will fail to update `origin/master`.